# Table numbering

Tags: tables, numbering

In my file, i have som tables, which are numbered incorrectly.
What I mean by that: I have two tables in chapter 4 and one in chapter 5. They are numbered as `4.1`, `4.2` and `5.1`, while I want them to be `1`, `2` and `3`. 
MWE is here:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\section{one}

...

\section{four}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table one}
%a table
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table two}
%a table
\end{table}

\section{five}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table three}
%a table
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{table}{chapter}`.

Comment: I think we've had this before; try searching for 'continuous table numbering'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `report` document class. The `\section` is not meant for reports (however, `\chapter` on the other hand *is*, so I suggest you use it instead). Just use `article` document class to fix the issue. Here, let me show you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \section{one}

    ...

    \section{four}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Table one}
        %a table
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Table two}
        %a table
    \end{table}

    \section{five}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Table three}
        %a table
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result is the following.

[image]

I wish you a nice day and plenty of future successes with LaTeX.

Comment: Why are `\section`s not meant for reports?

Comment: I found this claim in The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε (https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf). I can't tell the restrictions of mixing the document class and a command (since I only program in Java, Python and C++ I can't use Lua for my research on the topic), but it might be connected to the age of certain aspects of LaTeX (kind of similar to some `color` packages that caused plenty of errors when compiled in LaTeX2ε, as they were outdated). Furthermore, I tried every "trick" I knew, I used TeXnician's suggestion (which didn't work, at least for me), but without success.